# Como "juntar" os resultados do foreach

Tags: php, sql, foreach

Tenho um script para fazer multiplo upload de arquivos em php. Aí ao fazer o upload, queria que ele inserisse na tabela fotos, a informação com os nomes nesse formato: "nome1.jpg|nome2.jpg".

A query que uso para inserir é esse:

```
INSERT INTO foto (idlancamento, fotos)
VALUES ($idlancamento, $nomes);
```

Abaixo o script de fazer upload. Preciso que ele (concatene) os nomes para jogar em uma variavel `$nomes`:

```
$idlancamento=$_GET['idlancamento'];
echo '
    <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" id="file" name="files[]" multiple="multiple" accept="image/*" />
        <input type="submit" value="Upload!">
    </form>
';

$format_file = array("jpg", "png", "gif", "zip", "bmp");
$max_file_size = 1024*1000; //TAMANHO MÁXIMO
mkdir("/".$idlancamento, 0700);
$path = "/".$idlancamento."/"; // PASTA
$count = 0;
if(isset($_POST) and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){
    // Loop $_FILES para executar todos arquivos
    foreach ($_FILES['files']['name'] as $f => $name) {
        //cria nome do arquivo com o id do lançamento
        $name=$idlancamento.'_'.$name;
        if ($_FILES['files']['error'][$f] == 4) {
            continue; // Skip file if any error found
        }          
        if ($_FILES['files']['error'][$f] == 0) {              
            if ($_FILES['files']['size'][$f] > $max_file_size) {
                $message[] = "$name is too large!.";
                continue; // Skip large files
            }
            elseif( ! in_array(pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION), $format_file) ){
                $message[] = "$name is not a valid format";
                continue; // Skip invalid file formats
            }
            else{ // No error found! Move uploaded files 
                if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"][$f], $path.$name))
                $count++; // Number of successfully uploaded file
            }
        }
    }
    echo 'upload de '.$count.' arquivos';
}
```

Comment: E essa linha não funcionou? `$name=$idlancamento.'_'.$name;` Tenta inicilizar $name

Comment: acabei de resolver, coloquei: $names = .$name; aí no fim eu uso o $names

Answer (score 1):

Resolvi, adicionando a linha `$names.=$name.'|';` e uso o insert com valor $names depois de tudo

```
$idlancamento=$_GET['idlancamento'];
echo '
    <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" id="file" name="files[]" multiple="multiple" accept="image/*" />
        <input type="submit" value="Upload!">
    </form>
';

$format_file = array("jpg", "png", "gif", "zip", "bmp");
$max_file_size = 1024*1000; //TAMANHO MÁXIMO
mkdir("/".$idlancamento, 0700);
$path = "/".$idlancamento."/"; // PASTA
$count = 0;
if(isset($_POST) and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){
    // Loop $_FILES para executar todos arquivos
    foreach ($_FILES['files']['name'] as $f => $name) {
        //cria nome do arquivo com o id do lançamento
        $name=$idlancamento.'_'.$name;
        $names.=$name.'|';
        if ($_FILES['files']['error'][$f] == 4) {
            continue; // Skip file if any error found
        }          
        if ($_FILES['files']['error'][$f] == 0) {              
            if ($_FILES['files']['size'][$f] > $max_file_size) {
                $message[] = "$name is too large!.";
                continue; // Skip large files
            }
            elseif( ! in_array(pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION), $format_file) ){
                $message[] = "$name is not a valid format";
                continue; // Skip invalid file formats
            }
            else{ // No error found! Move uploaded files 
                if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"][$f], $path.$name))
                $count++; // Number of successfully uploaded file
            }
        }
    }
    echo 'upload de '.$count.' arquivos';
}
```